# Is there any restrictions on IOS while publishing on AppStore? App 100% based on HTML page come from serve

Tags: ios, app-store

Can we develop 100% complete web page application? On client side, there won't be any ui component. 
It will consist only web view. All pages will be there on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple may reject your app if all it does is wrap a web site in a UIWebView. You need to have more functionality in your app than just loading a web page.

From the [app review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for iOS:

**4.2 Minimum Functionality
Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your app doesn’t provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, it may not be accepted.**

You may want to investigate developing your company's app as a mobile web app. There's plenty of [information published by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/safari/) (and others) about how to write mobile web apps that function similarly to native iOS apps.